# POST Form don't post any data to the server in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two action, one to get the form and the other to receive data from the form
the problem now is the form don't send any data to the server if i use The View Model that's have employees and department class, but if i use employee class only on view and on post action it's work fine
here is the code 
Create GET Action

```
   public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var deps = _context.Departments.ToList();
        var empDeps = new EmployeeDepartmentViewModel()
        {
            Employee = new Employee(),
            Department = deps
        };
        return View(empDeps);
    }
```

create POST Action

```
    [HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public void Create(EmployeeDepartmentViewModel employee)
{
    Response.Write("<h1>" + employee.Employee.Name + "</h1>");
}
```

view code

```
 @model EmployeesDemo.Models.ViewModels.EmployeeDepartmentViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Employees", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Employee</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Employee.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" name="Create" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

now to keep things simple, I want just to receive the name from the view and print it in Response

**Update :**
When i use FormCollection I can read the values from the form, but i really don't know what is the problem in using EmployeeDepartmentViewModel and why i can't read data using that in my action.

Comment: if you use fiddler to capture the post to the server, what does the body of the request look like? Additionally, what does the rendered html look like for the employee name textbox?

Comment: in fiddler gives me 500 as result but in the network tap the form don't send any thing to the server, i have this exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="Employee Name must be between 5:50 char." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="5" data-val-required="The Employee Name field is required." id="Employee_Name" name="Employee.Name" type="text" value="">

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't been composing view models with domain entities. The purpose of a view model is to map your UI elements back to a class that reflects only the data that is on the screen.  You can them map your view models into domain entities as needed.  your null reference exception is probably due to the model binder not being about to bind your posted data to the Employee class.  Is also good to guard against bad data by checking against ModelState.IsValid when you enter your POST action.

Comment: @Fran but this don't fix my error, and the form don't post any data to the server any way

Comment: It did post because you can see it when you use FormCollection.  What's happening is the default modelbinder can't bind the wire representation to your model.  Simplify your viewmodel to only what you want to send back.

Comment: i dont believe limiting the data being sent back will help him as non-posted properties will result in their default values. i'm guessing there is some other error that is not being described by OP here as he eluded to having a null reference exception in his comment response to me. @AbdallaEliwa where is the error being thrown? You're saying youre getting an error on the server side (null reference exception) but also saying that the network tab shows no request sent to the server- that doesn't make sense unless its happening in ur view. in that case, where in the view does this happen?

Comment: @GregH Exception happen when i try to write the name i got from view
so it happen in the server, and like i say in update when i use FormCollection every thing working fine but i don't know where is the mistake where i use my view model

Comment: @GregH That's why i'm telling him to simplify his viewmodel and remove any references to his domain object.  Just have a single property Name, that he then sends back to the server. 1. to verify that it's a modelbinding problem with his viewmodel and 2. to get any domain references out of his viewmodel.